# KineticJS Data to URl into an <img> tag instead of new window

Tags: kineticjs, data-url

I'm making a game that is similar to the [KineticJS drag and drop sample](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/).
I've combined it with the [save image feature](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-stage-data-url-with-kineticjs/) so users can keep the end result of what they've made.

Does anyone know how I can control the placement of the resulting image of the canvas? I'd like to include the option for users to share/post their image to facebook, email it or save it.

I assume it's either a change to the

```
function() {
         stage.toDataURL({callback: function(dataUrl) { window.open(dataUrl);} });  }, false);
      }
```

or some extra code after?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would be right. You can save your dataURL and you just have to manipulate it as an image.

```
var myDataUrl;  //place outside of scope of function for saving
stage.toDataURL({
    callback: function(dataUrl){
      // do something with the data url
      // like window.open(dataUrl); 
      // you can do anything do anything really, like
      myDataUrl = dataUrl;

      var img= new Image(); //or document.createElement('img');
      img.src= myDataUrl; 

      //(new Image()).src = "myDataUrl"; //or the shortcut way

      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(img);
    },
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    quality: 0.5
});
```